# remove event listener in vue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, addeventlistener

i need to remove the event listener. i'm calling to some method from the function executed within the event listener, so i need to use to es6 syntax. i couldn't use named functions. how can i remove the event listener

```
methods :
    initCanvas : function(x, y, width, height) {
        //do something
    },
    some_method : function() {
        let svgObjectEl = // some logic will give the object elemenet embedding the svg
        svgObjectEl.addEventListener('load', () => {
            //let x,y,width, height has some value
            // some code here
            this.initCanvas(x, y, width, height);         
        });   
        svgObjectEl.removeEventListener('load', ??);
}
```

Comment: You need to store it in a variable.

Comment: can you write it out.

Comment: wouldn't `<svg @load.once="listener" ...` do it ?

Comment: @birdspider No. i had to perform some logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
methods: {
  initCanvas (x, y, width, height) {
    //do something
  },
  some_method() {
    svgObjectEl.options = { x: 12, y: 13, … }
    svgObjectEl.addEventListener('load', this.listener)
  },
  listener(evt) {
    // some code here
    this.initCanvas(evt.target.options)
    svgObjectEl.removeEventListener('load', this.listener)    
  }
}
```

Comment: there are some variable x, y, width, height in method "some_method". how can i pass them to method listener

Comment: svgObjectEl was not found in listener. so i tweak my code little bit.

Comment: I was hoping to see `this.$on()` and something equivalent for remove